# EPPlus ExcelPackage ByteArray to PDF File

Tags: asp.net-core, epplus, asp.net-core-3.1

In our `Asp.Net Core API`  application we load a templated Excelfile using `EPPlus`. Add in the data from the database and use `.GetAsByteArray()` to return a generate Excel file.

I now need give the user the ability to download this file as a PDF as well. However, the documentation seems limited on this.

I found the following link here;

[PdfRpt.Core from EPPlus](https://github.com/VahidN/PdfReport.Core/blob/master/src/PdfRpt.Core.FunctionalTests/ExcelToPdfReport.cs)

However, this doesn't use the official EPPlus repo.

I am currently using `EPPlus v 5.2.0`.

Is it possible for me to convert the `ExcelPackage` to a PDF byte array without saving the file to disk?

Comment: I have the same problem now, did you ever found a solution ?

Comment: It's been a while since @GuidoG asked, so I'll ask so well. Has anyone come up with a solution to this? I've got the same exact problem in front of me.

Comment: In the end I used Spire.Xls to pass the excel sheet I had generated with EPPlus, write to a memory stream and convert that way.